# Extracting URL links from a File

Tags: python, regex

Following code is to extract /support/security/*.html links from a file(urlfile contain about 1000 links) to urlsort file using regex,But i'm weak in regex can anyone show me how to do that...?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re,sys

fileHandle = open('urlfile', 'r')
f1 = open('urlsort', 'w')
for line in fileHandle.readlines():

    links = re.findall(r"(\/support\/security\/*.html.*?)", line)
    for link in links:
        sys.stdout = f1
        print ('%s' % (link[0]))
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__


 f1.close()
 fileHandle.close()
```

Comment: This should be in stackoverflow.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex has two mistakes, a missing `.` before the first `*` and an extra `?` near the end.

Here is some code that writes urls matching your pattern to `urlsort` using some python idioms.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

with open('urlfile', 'r') as urls_in:
    with open('urlsort', 'w') as urls_out:
        for line in urls_in:
            links = re.findall(r"(\/support\/security\/bulletins\/.*.html)", line)
            if links:
                urls_out.write("%s\n" % links[0])
```